# Cross-platform live charts in F#

Tags: .net, charts, f#, cross-platform

I am currently using XPlot to display charts with F# but I now need live charts (I will add points at regular interval) which do not appear to be an option in XPlot.

Is there a cross-platform way to get live charts in F# ?

edit : I am looking for a solution that will be used in a library so I am aiming for a unique package (XPlot filled that role) and not a thing.GTK/thing.WPF/etc group. Otherwise OxyPlot was indeed a good solution.

At worst a solution would be to recode something from scratch using the current, limited but cross-platform, drawing library but I have been confronted with some strange behaviours drawing polygons with mono in the past and would rather avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

[OxyPlot](http://www.oxyplot.org/) is one such library. Supports WPF/Winforms/Xamarin/GTK.

Comment: Thank you, it is not exctly what I am looking for (see the edit) but it is a solution.